# Meaning of "see the way forward"?

Tags: meaning

Here two examples:

> - "But I don't think football's in crisis because a crisis would be if
>     you can't **see the way forward.**"
> - "There are those who **see the way forward** as limited to securing
>     investments and channeling all resources to expand access to available
>     diagnostic services and curative drugs."

What does the phrase "**see the way forward**" mean?

Comment: Hi Watery Honey, you can look that up in a dictionary: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-way-forward

Comment: Hi, what about the verb see? I looked it up in many dictionaries, but there was no collocation as such.

Comment: "Know the path to success"

Comment: Check out the UNDERSTAND meaning here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see

Answer (score 1):

It means to envision the (presumably correct) way to proceed in order to arrive at a particular (usually implicit, unstated, and often quite general) goal.

In the first example, they are discussing a crisis that would presumably have some negative consequences for the game. The person is stating that it would only be considered a crisis if "you" (meaning a general "someone") didn't know how to proceed in dealing with whatever is deemed to constitute the crisis in such a way that the negative consequences would be minimised or even avoided altogether.

In the second example, "securing investments and channeling all resources to expand access to available diagnostic services and curative drugs" (and doing *only that*, i.e. "limited to") is seen as the way to achieve some goal (presumably a healthy populace, or something like that, if it is public health-related).